# How to: Fullwidth select element with Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Using Tailwind CSS, How can I get a select element to stretch the full width of its containing element?  Here is my code:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-4">

<!-- left column -->
<div class="col-span-3 bg-gray-100 px-2 py-4">
    <label for="testSelect">Select a Type</label>
    <select id="testSelect" class="block w-max">
        <option value="1" class="block w-max" selected>Test 1</option>
        <option value="2" class="block w-max">Test 2</option>
    </select>
</div>

</div>
```

The console shows that the display is set to block on the select element, but it still only takes as much width as the content of the options requires.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please make use of `flex` and [`w-full`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width) classes.

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-4">
  <!-- left column -->
  <div class="col-span-3 bg-gray-100 px-2 py-4">
    <label for="testSelect">Select a Type</label>
    <select id="testSelect" class="flex w-full"> <!-- From block  -->
      <option value="1" class="block w-full" selected>Test 1</option> <!-- From w-max -->
      <option value="2" class="block w-full">Test 2</option> <!-- From w-max -->
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Tailwind playground:** https://play.tailwindcss.com/raT0G6ZpkH

Comment: Class property on the option element does nothing. 
See docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#styling_with_css